# How to make images readable in script while direct access is denied

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I can't find out how to deny direct access to an image folder and images while it would be readable on the web page.

Thank for your answer.

Comment: You cannot. Otherwise the browser would not be able to get at the images

Comment: As a workaround you can check the referrer in the request header. But its not a very secure method. Some browser settings will omit such data and wont be able to show the image.

Comment: Are you using php sessions?

Answer (score 0):

You can deny direct access to image folder but you can't deny access to images within it because browser basically accesses those images in the same way you access it in your browser.

You can see those network calls (for chrome)

```
Press F12 (Inspect) > Network
```

Here you would find list of all calls that browser makes.

[image]

---

**Restricting access to Image Directory**

If you want to restrict access to image folder, then a simple way is to define a blank `index.html` file inside that folder.

Or you can also put some dummy content like:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<h3>You're not authorized to view the contents of this page...</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace all your image references from:

```
<img src='/path/to/restricted/folder/image.png' />
```

To:

```
<?php $base64 = base64_encode(file_get_contents('/path/to/restricted/folder/image.png')); ?>
<img src='data:image/png;base64,<?=$base64?>' />
```

You can then create and `.htaccess` file in the folder and add in it.

```
deny from all
```

However keep in mind this will greatly increase the page loading time for users since all images will be pre-read rather than read asynchronously.